# How to do full text search in postresql efficiently through multiple models?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search

I am working on rails application I have three different models as follows

product model

```
id | product_name| product_description
```

User model

```
id | name | location | timestamp
```

Shopping Model

```
id | product_id | user_id | location
```

Now in my application user can search for different products.
Suppose product description is xyz & somebody from New York bought it. So Now I want to search in such a way that if somebody searches for xyz the entries from product table will be returned & also when somebody searches for New York it should return the all product bought from New York.

I have created a view of product and shopping model table as follows.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT product.id , product.description , shopping.location 
  FROM product LEFT JOIN shopping ON product.id = shopping.product_id group by  product.id, product.description,shopping.location
```

**I am using texticle gem to search through this view.**

But problem with the above view is suppose 10 persons from 10 different locations bought xyz  product then in the result set for the search of product description there will be duplicate results. How to avoid such duplication? Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT p.id, p.product_name, p.product_description, s.location FROM product p, shopping s WHERE p.description='xyz' OR s.location='New York' AND p.id=shopping.product_id ORDER BY p.product_name

Comment: hey while searching you can enter one term at a time u can either enter xyz or newyork so my problem still not solved

Comment: try using `p.description='xyz' OR s.location='New York'` and let me know if it works